# window.onload triggered again on back-button in Firefox 30

Tags: javascript

I have a function that creates bar (HTML) at the top of the page. 
The bar is very simple, it contains 3 things: Company logo, list of links (table to be correct) and control element.

Bars behavior: When user resizes the browser window, then list of links is shortened or extended, depends how many links fits inside without scrollbar. But the rest of the bar remains unchanged.

This means that I only work with html elements of the list (never call `createBar` again).

Everything is perferct except one thing. When user goes on another page and then returns back, then whole bar is duplicated, **but only if user has firefox 30 and browsers zoom level is not 100% (he used ctrl+/ctrl-)**. In chrome everything is fine.

From my point of view, when I click back, then page appears with 1 bar, but page is still loading and after 100-500ms another bar appears. If I go another link and back again, there are 2 bars and third appears after a while. So it looks like last state is loaded from bf cache, but then `onload` is called again and this creates another bar. So what I tried was put breakpoints in my js code, but it didn't catch anything. According to Firefox debugger `onload` is not triggered again.

Skeleton of my code:

```
TopBar = function () {
    this.init();
};

TopBar.prototype.init = function () {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", this.dataSource, true);
    xhr.responseType = "text";
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState != 4) {
            return;
        }

        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            try {
                var serverResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                this.createBar(serverResponse);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error("Parse JSON failed. ");
            }
        }
    }.bind(this);

    xhr.send();
};

TopBar.prototype.createBar = function (data) {
    // I create whole bar HTML here and append it to body

    window.addEventListener('resize', this.recalculate.bind(this));
};

TopBar.prototype.recalculate = function () {
    this.barEl.style.visibility = "hidden";
    if (window.innerWidth < 900) {
        this.barEl.style.display = "none";
        return;
    }

    // else recalculate part of the bar and display it
    // it means change some html,

    this.barEl.style.visibility = "visible";
};

window.onload = function () {
    new TopBar();
};
```

Comment: I think it's `resize` that's triggering. Somehow your `createBar` function is attached to `resize`. Check the value of `this` from the `.createBar` assignment, log it to the console to make sure it has the value you expect.

Comment: @IvyLynx I thought the same thing first, so I already debug it and I'm very sure it is not called again with resize. Also notice that simple resize and zoom works. It is broken only when backbutton + zoomchange + firefox. I might disable bfcache with rewritting `onunload`, but it is not my cup of tea.

Comment: hmm well, it might be some other event but regardless, a quick fix might be to enforce a single instance of your bar, making it a singleton of sorts. If _that_ doesn't work then something very strange goes on with back + zoom.